# Histogram does not reflect quantum device results

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I created the following code to run a simple circuit through a quantum device twice.  My purpose was to show the effects of noise with different arrangements of qubits when using ibmq_belem.

```
#Run circuit with two different qubit layouts
from qiskit import IBMQ, execute
#Load account
provider=IBMQ.load_account()
#Choose device
backend=provider.get_backend('ibmq_belem')
C=[]
for initial_layout in [[0,3],[2,4]]:
    job=execute(circuit, backend, initial_layout=initial_layout).result()
    c=result.get_counts()
    C.append(c)
```

followed by
`plot_histogram([C[0],C[1]],title="Comparing Noise")`
to create the histogram which give me ...
[image]

Which does not reflect any of the noise that I see in my results taken directly from IBMQ which shows the first and second runthroughs respectivly as ...
[image]

[image]

These are clearly not the identically perfect versions that my C set seems to have created.  This makes my question; What have I done wrong in coding this that C is not accurately reflecting my counts?

**Edit:** I note that it has somehow decided to take the counts from when I ran this circuit on a simulator in a prior cell using the following code.

```
simulator=Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
result=execute(circuit,backend=simulator).result()
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))
```

This code had been run before I ever created the set C, so I did not expect it to interfere, but now I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: You have a typo inside the for loop. Change this row: `c=result.get_counts()` to this: `c = job.result().get_counts()`.

Comment: @Ohad You found that just as I did!  Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!  It was using my result label from the initial coding when I used the simulator and appending that twice to my set C.  So in my code I have now changed `c=result.get_counts()` to `c=job.get_counts()` as that was the 'job' I wanted the results from!  And now all is beautiful and full of noise!